# Responsive Typography with rem - Baseline fontsize in % or px?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, typography

I am trying to implement a responsive typography solution with SCSS using rems in order to use media queries only on the baseline font-size in html and not on every element.

I found different approaches to the font size in html:

```
html { font-size: 100%;  }  // uses the default browser font-size
html { font-size: 62.5%; }  // 62.5% = 10px to facilitate rem calculation
html { font-size: 16px;  }  // uses 16px
```

Assuming that I would take the [62.5%-approach suggested by Jonathan Snook](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem), I could then assign my headings and paragraph quiet easily using [a mixin for px-fallbacks:](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/less-mixin-for-rem-font-sizing/)

```
@mixin font-size($sizeValue: 1.6) {
    font-size: ($sizeValue * 10) + px;
    font-size: $sizeValue + rem;
}

h1 { @include font-size(3.2); }         // 32px
h2 { @include font-size(2.6); }         // 26px
h3 { @include font-size(2.2); }         // 22px
h4 { @include font-size(1.8); }         // 18px
h5 { @include font-size(1.6); }         // 16px
h6 { @include font-size(1.4); }         // 14px
```

I could then apply media queries to the html font-sizes to scale the typography at different resolutions , something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { html { font-size: 56.3%; } } // 56.3% = 9px
@media (min-width: 992px) { html { font-size: 62.5%; } } // 62.5% = 10px
@media (min-width: 1200px) { html { font-size: 68.8%; } } // 68.8% = 11px
```

**My questions:**

**1. What is the best approach to the font-size baseline (px vs 100% vs 62.5%)?**

**2. What is the best overall approach to responsive typography with SASS / SCSS?**

Comment: This seems like a very broad question?

Comment: I find so many different suggestions on the internet on how to approach responsive typography, but I cannot find a generally accepted, standardized solution. Everyone seems to do it differently.

Comment: I think what you've got there is a fairly standard approach.  In my mind it more boils down to does it work for the project/design.  As the reason we do this is to make our lives easier.  If it does this, then it's probably right.

Comment: 62.5% is 9.375 pixels (at least on my computer) so I don't see how that would facilitate rem calculations

Comment: That is the issue with the 62.5% approach: It is interpreted differently in different browsers, which makes me think a baseline in px makes more sense. Also we cannot control 100% in the user's browser (could be set to a completely strange value).

Comment: px is working everywhere, if you don't want the crossbrowser issues, so you should use px. It is only my opinion

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the "best approach", but this is what I've been doing lately:

1. Set your base size in pixels. It will be consistent across browsers and is easier to reason about.
2. Baseline in pixels, all type sizes for elements in rems, and then just reset your baseline size on media queries (in pixels).

This is a great article by Trent Walton that is less about implementation and more about best practices, but I find it really helpful: http://trentwalton.com/2012/06/19/fluid-type/

Not sure I answered your question, but it's a pretty in-depth topic!

Answer (score 0):

My SCSS fluid typography, very comfortably:

```
html { 
    @include fluid-property(font-size, 1rem, 1.5rem, 320px, 1600px);
}


/// Fluid property/properties
/// Examples:
///      html           { @include fluid-property(font-size, 14px, 20px, 320px, 1366px); }                          // single property
///      html           { @include fluid-property(font-size, 1em, 2em, 320px, 1366px); }                            // single property
///      h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 { @include fluid-property((padding-left, padding-right), 10rem, 20rem, 48em, 64em); }       // multiple properties with same values
/// All units must be of the type: px / em / rem.
@mixin fluid-property($properties, $min-value, $max-value, $min-screen, $max-screen) {
    @each $property in $properties {
        #{$property}: $min-value;
    }
    @include media-min($min-screen) {
        @each $property in $properties {
            #{$property}: calc-interpolation($min-value, $max-value, $min-screen, $max-screen); 
        }
    }
    @include media-min($max-screen) {
        @each $property in $properties {
            #{$property}: $max-value;
        }
    }
}
@function calc-interpolation($min-value, $max-value, $min-screen, $max-screen) {
    $u-min-value: unit($min-value);
    $a: 0; $b: 0;
    @if ($u-min-value == em) {
        $a: em($max-value - $min-value) / em($max-screen - $min-screen);
        $b: $min-value - $a * em($min-screen); 
    } @else if ($u-min-value == rem) {
        $a: rem($max-value - $min-value) / rem($max-screen - $min-screen);
        $b: $min-value - $a * rem($min-screen); 
    } @else {
        $a: px($max-value - $min-value) / px($max-screen - $min-screen);
        $b: $min-value - $a * px($min-screen); 
    }    
    $sign: "+";
    @if ($b < 0) {
        $sign: "-";
        $b: abs($b);
    }
    @return calc(#{$a*100}vw #{$sign} #{$b});
}
```

It will render next CSS:

```
html { font-size: 1rem; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) { html { font-size: calc(0.625vw + 0.875rem); } }

@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) { html { font-size: 1.5rem; } }
```